# When was Gmail filter last used?

Tags: gmail-filters

I have several filters that date to WAAAY back. Some are twit filters. Some are to control system message for a forum I stopped participating in.

However, I can't find a way to see if they're being used any more. I'd love to see a "last triggered" date.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Sure, I suppose I could leave them there, but the list is getting pretty long and it's hard to find stuff.

*Let me clarify*

I'm looking to find a way to tell when a filter was last triggered. If I have a filter that hasn't acted on a message since, say, September '08, it's probably safe to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently not currently possible in any reasonable way.

I've made a [Gmail Feature Request](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs) for this. Maybe someday...

Answer (score 1):

If you go to edit it, and test search, it will run the filter again including any emails that were filtered when they came in, assuming they haven't been deleted since.

Comment: That's really only helpful if they've come in in the last 30 days and I haven't manually emptied the trash.

Comment: It's the best it lets you do.